# Acceptable length of video for mobile?

Tags: mobile, video, responsive, best-practice

We have video content that will supplement written content on our responsive site.  All of the videos will be less than a minute.

Are there any guidelines for length/size of video content on mobile sites?  I suspect that as long as it's supplemental and not primary, the user can decide to engage at their own discretion.

Thoughts?

Comment: All videos should be as long as necessary but no longer.

Comment: Re the close votes: While the question is formulated in a way that asks for thoughts and not answers, there is still significant and deterministic research regarding the topic. Enough so that answers are not opinion based.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer - There are plenty of research available on this topic but the answer(s) to this question will be specific to the OP's website and won't be of universal significance. Also, video lengths as a topic is subjective and circumstantial. There's no *one size fits all* answer. This question is nearly 4 y/o which makes it a little ancient. Nowadays, the mobile devices have larger and better screens and a big chunk of people use it to even watch feature length films

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"all of the videos will be less than a minute"

That it perfectly fine to be honest. The question you should be asking is who is the target audience, do they have good internet access/bandwidth to actually view the content ? I work for media company with majority users in Japan and Indonesia and we try to serve right content to the right audience.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wistia video analytics, the longer the video, the more likely user attention span will lower.

I think anything between 0 to 1 minute is perfect. A little more would also be okay if you have a lot of content.

[image: http://blog.apps-builder.com/app-promotional-video/]

[Source](http://blog.apps-builder.com/app-promotional-video/)

Comment: I think you should include a link to the corresponding article :)

Comment: Yeah I thought I had added an image description with the article link. But seems it doesn't show the image description.